# Outlook Task Assignment gives and Error

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, tasks

I have created a Task in outlook. When I assign this task to my collegues, I get an error message:

An error has occured: public member 'Recipients' on type 'TaskRequestItem' not found

When I click OK, the task has got created and assigned correctly. A mail also goes out and my collegue can see the task.

Is there some setting that needs to be changed so that I can stop getting this error message.

Edit1:
I have Synchronized the address book using send/Receive -> Download address book. The sync was complete, however the issue persists.
On some other machines there is no issue, hence this looks more like a config/setting issue.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using? Can you go to Tools>Send/Receive and sucessfully "Download Address Book"?

Comment: No errors in the Sync Issues folder near the bottom regarding that address book download?

Comment: Nope it said downloaded successfully

Comment: Sorry, I HAD to check based on my suspicion, and it is easy to miss an error there.